# TypeScript different classes implementation with same interface. Checking fields of their instances

Tags: typescript, oop, types, interface, monads

try to implement 2 classes for some business logic inside my application, here is some pseudo code (I use `object` and `string` types, but the main idea to specify each type for each logic)

Have some interface and class declarations;

```
interface IResult<T, E> {
    result: T;
    err: E;
}

class Fail<E> implements IResult<null, E> {
    private readonly _error: E;

    constructor(error: E) {
        this._error = error;
    }

    get err(): E {
        return this._error;
    }

    get result(): null {
        return null;
    }
}

class Success<T> implements IResult<T, null> {
    private readonly _result: T;

    constructor(result: T) {
        this._result = result;
    }

    get err() {
        return null;
    }

    get result(): T {
        return this._result;
    }
}
```

I need to get one of these instances from some service, for example `DetailsFactory`
I specify it's response type, `Success` should return `object` and `Fail` should return `string`

```
type Result<T, E> = Success<T> | Fail<E>;
```

And also use interface for it

```
interface IDetailsFactory {
    make(): Result<object, string>;
}
```

```
class DetailsFactory implements IDetailsFactory {
    private readonly _type: string;
    private _operation: object;

    constructor(type: string) {
        this._type = type;
    }

    public make() {
        switch (this._type) {
            case '1': this._operation = {type: '1', name: 'First'}; break;
            case '2': this._operation = {type: '2', name: 'Second'}; break;
            case '3': this._operation = {type: '3', name: 'Third'}; break;
            default: return new Fail('Type is not specified');
        }

        return new Success(this._operation);
    }
}
```

And I can use it like this:

```
const detailsFactory = new DetailsFactory('1');
const {result, err} = detailsFactory.make();
```

Here i'm received expected object in `result` field, and `null` in `err`, but when I try to check

```
if (!err) {
    console.log(result.name);
}
```

I receive TS error `Error:(96, 14) TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.`
Of course I can check `result` instead `!err` but it's not such beautiful and i want to make early exit from function.

So the question is: how i can tell to TS that if i hadn't any errors `(!err = true)` trust me and get data from `result` field? Make it so that it stops thinking that `result` field may be `null` when `error = null`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the non-null assertion operator can help you here:

```
if (!err) {
    console.log(result!.name);
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator

Comment: Thanks, very quick and simple, but may be we can modify only backside? (interface and classes) because the people who'll use it may don't know about `!`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a discriminated union to get the compiler to narrow the types as you expect. Unfortunately TS can't currently narrow one variable based on another, you can only narrow a single variable.

Also you need some extra generics to forward the actual return type.

```
type DetailsFactoryResult = 
     | { type: '1', name: string }
     | { type: '2', name: string }
     | { type: '3', name: string }

class DetailsFactory implements IDetailsFactory<DetailsFactoryResult> {
    // ...    
    public make(): Result<DetailsFactoryResult, string> {
        // ...
    }
}

const detailsFactory = new DetailsFactory("1");
const r = detailsFactory.make();

if (r.err == null) {
    console.log(r.result.name);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=57&ssc=58&pln=57&pc=5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICUIGcCuAbMAHgBUAaZAUQD5kBvAKGSeSm3zAC5liBuR56FC4U+AX3r0EeOFizIAYnGB5C1ZMAC2ABzwQNEcHIxsChEPjzk1DZsi1RgANziQWEOABMA9iDwBPZAB9QS8hSj5+JgQfLDAoHAQwUIAKELCKAEo6SNtkMAALYCwAOmCoKFDkAF5kNL5bcRyAcwgwWvLkjOFs3OZWMBwoEDzCkrKKqHrmRtsWttZcAk6uczw8Ht63AaHkVbwppnFGqRk5AGUEpFkSGk0dPQMwI0xFojJdixobZnsnFxRWJ4fP4ggt2FxeBJbNEQLF4okUmCCBCst9egUiqUkW0atiDsgZsw5u0oJ0Nr1+oNhnt8YSmMTsctuOTcpSdhixnickcJGA-FoUC92CQrDQahcEFcsDdkAAfBRKFTUCKgSCwRAoVAAEVaiqwigRUD8MrRyA0cAA1hAmULTO84aAmlQxLz+SgdWA9QakkbbTjkDk5XQ8m6uAByACMYfIIDg+i4DpATQJgfltBDAvDACZo7s4xAE3FHSncmmMwXkGGAMy52Px5CJ5PHaSyZAer2IH0BO66fSGNDt5T6zuhY2DvDDw1+P1fHK-ZyuQHeXwBQJ8zMNotJ-Hz-5BLwCqAuYA+ACEXHHk67foi0JicQSPuS64rjdRgeYHNKL+q5dpUJ+HAACM8GABAzUta0umQP1CEvb1Rz9chG1nTYGwAd2AMAEHyZBn1Gb83XfNDoRkFBIzDLgv0CA9oGPHxf1oF9wyjGN83DeRgCgWIw1EHhkCAwELXxNCEDIyscyogiaMPejhhqJjQwk2t2MrM4IBhDxeP4wT3GEj9ejErByJrKTMRkuiwBPeS6GYysazY+sw2IQooC0viBKEkTNg8CB4HBLYqV2CB0IVZRkmct11DkEAvDaLABQQYAYGACAtIybzDgAilWiCkAQuQCUpXw8zaKPKyfAy7l6GOe9kF8z0hwQo1f3y0L4JHI1kgAIgjbqqphWIWF-BqOynYpzStToVRgPCoGKQRqhqPZiOYQavF0Yo8C8Jpknm7FijrCAqtEIA)

Comment: Thanks, yes it works, I want to make something like API for business logic response, it this case the user should know that he need to check strict to null and create additional generics... May be there is another way to realize such functionality...

Answer (score 0):

Also, I can add function for checking the result to interface and implement it with type checking, for example

```
interface IResult<T, E> {
    result: T;
    err: E;
    isOk(): boolean;
}
```

```
class Success<T> implements IResult<T, null> {
    private readonly _result: T;

    constructor(result: T) {
        this._result = result;
    }

    get err() {
        return null;
    }

    get result(): T {
        return this._result!;
    }

    isOk(): this is Success<NonNullable<T>> {
        return Boolean(this._result);
    }
}
```

And then I can use it like

```
const detailsFactory = new DetailsFactory('1');
const data = detailsFactory.make();

if (data.isOk()) {
    console.log(data.result.name);
}
```

But I'm still looking for a more elegant solution and getting data through destructuring and simple `!err` checking like in my question above